# What is the working principle of this circuit?

Tags: how-does-it-work

This is a circuit for a battery condition indicator:

[image: this is a circuit for as battery condition indicator]

- How can I determine the base, the emitter and the collector of the transistor?
- How does this circuit work?

Comment: If it's supposed to light the LED, I don't think it works at all.  The LED is backwards.

Comment: deelaka srimal - Hi, Where did that schematic originally come from? In order to comply with the [site rule on referencing](/help/referencing), details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided next to that material. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) then [edit] the question & add its *name* & *link* (URL). If the original source was a printed book or other offline material, then [edit] the question & add a normal citation (see the linked rule for details). TY (Please see the [tour] & [help] for the site rules.)

Comment: Is this school work?

Comment: the transistor symbol indicates the collector,  base and emitter connections ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=transistor+symbol&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LED is backward.
The behavior is "very" dependent of the supply voltage ...
Note the value of the parameter "a" for some change of the LED.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The transistor pin designations can be found from Google or any transistor datasheet.

The circuit, as it is drawn, is known as one-shot strobe. The way it works is you keep cranking the battery voltage up until you exceed the reverse  breakdown voltage of the LED and transistor. At some point, The LED will flash one time. Depending on the current capacity of the battery; the LED, transistor, or both may physically "pop" never to be used again.

If the LED's polarity is flipped, likely the way the designer intended it, the circuit becomes more practical.

Resistor v/r is likely a thermistor or photo resistor that changes its resistance based on its respective physical property. This sets up a voltage divider with the circled 1k resistor. The divided voltage drives the base of the first transistor (read from left to right) and adds gain to the changes of the v/r resistor. The second transistor acts as a switch to turn the LED on and off.

An improvement would be to put the 680 ohm resistor on the top (collector) of Q2 and in series with the LED. Then tie the bottom (emitter) of Q2 to battery negative. This will give sharper LED on off transitions. Because the way it is now, the LED will tend to fade on an off as Resistor v/r gets close to the trip point. Or, maybe that is the intended behavior...